# How to show only images with a certain tag with NextGEN gallery plugin?

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

As described, how can I show only the images with a certain tag on a Wordpress blog that use `NextGEN Gallery` as gallery plugin?

NextGEN Gallery version is 1.5.5 but I can upgrade to 1.6.2 (last) if necessary. I would like to display images with a specified tag on a new Wordpress Page.

Comment: You ask about a "tag". Is that tag from Wordpress or does the NextGEN gallery has it's own tagging mechanism?

Comment: http://awfulcool.com/uncategorized/how-to-create-a-nextgen-gallery-tag-cloud/comment-page-1/#comment-96

Answer (score 1):

Alternative? http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/media-library-plus-plugin

Comment: The problem is that I have already a big amount of pictures loaded into NextGEN gallery, I don't like too much to move whole of them to another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly where you want the images to display on the site, whether you mean in posts, a slideshow or gallery view etc.

You could however use the 'manage gallery' options and check the box 'exclude' next to the photo you don't want to display.

If you can clarify you requirements, as well as nextgen gallery plugin version, I may be able to give you a better suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I added now this information to the question's body.

Comment: ok, well i would upgrade to the latest version and then use the exclude function. That should achieve what you want I think.